# python managing redundant data by incrementing no. in a text file

Tags: python

I am new to python.I have a text file, i need to avoid the redundancy not by deleting ,but by incrementing the number in a text file if the lines are found to be same.

Please help!Answers will be appreciated!
eg of a random text file:

```
hello ram1
hello ram1
hello gate1
hello gate1
```

Expected output:

```
hello ram1
hello ram2
hello gate1
hello gate2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expression and [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

numbers = defaultdict(int)
with open('/path/to/textfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = re.sub(r'\d+', '', line.rstrip())  # Remove numbers.
        numbers[line] += 1  # Increment number for the same line
        print('{}{}'.format(line, numbers[line]))
```

---

**UPDATE** using slice notation, dictionary.

```
import re

numbers = {}
with open('1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = re.split(r'(\d+)', line.strip())
        words = tuple(row[::2])  # Extract non-number parts to use it as key
        if words not in numbers:
            numbers[words] = [int(n) for n in row[1::2]]  # extract number parts.
        numbers[words] = [n+1 for n in numbers[words]]  # Increase numbers.
        row[1::2] = map(str, numbers[words])  # Assign back numbers
        print(''.join(row))
```

Comment: I was going to propose using `defaultdict(lamba: count(1))` then just `.format(line, next(numbers[line]))` - Also, probably don't need the regex - it's possible that `line.rstrip('0123456789\n')` might also be sufficient

Comment: @falsetru its fine ,but when i put some no. in middle,its like: `heo.1o
heo.1o` and it showing as`heo.1o1 , heo.1o1` instead of `heo.1o , heo.2o`

Comment: @JonClements, `number[line] += 1` is needed because default factory function is called only for missing key. And `lambda: count(1)` should be `count(1).next` or `count(1).__next__` according to python version.

Comment: @aseyraamsram, Is it possible the line contian multile numbers? (for example `he2llo wo5ld`

Comment: @falsetru yes, it will contain multiple numbers!

Comment: @aseyraamsram, If there are three line of `he2llo wo5ld`, what is the expected output?

Comment: @falsetru for the incrementing the 3 lines like `he2llo wo5ld, he3llo wo6ld, he4llo wo7ld`

Comment: @aseyraamsram, What if there are different numbers with same structure? `he2llo wo5ld`, `he9llo wo9ld`, `he2llo wo4ld`

Comment: @falsetru different no.s with same structure need not be considered,because i will keep it as it is!since its not getting redundant of same no.s!

Comment: @falsetru even so, nothing wrong with `lambda: count(1)` then using `next()` in the format as I demonstrated... (mind you, this question got very complicated very quickly - I read it the same as you)

Comment: @falsetru thats fantastic,but a little help, because ,even its for same line,i need to leave the text in "", i mean `he1("yes") , he1("fine")` it should also increment leaving the unmatch text within "" and increment as  `he1("yes") , he2("fine")`

Comment: @JonClements, You're right. I missed `next`.

Comment: @aseyraamsram, as Jon Clements commented, the question is getting complicated. How about post a separated question.

Comment: @aseyraamsram use that time to make sure to list all the rules that apply (so might be stuff you've mentioned here in the comments), but if you can provide sample input, the rules, and expected output etc... That'd be an interesting question...

Comment: @JonClements fine,i will really see to that!

Comment: @falsetru posted the new updated question,please help , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590030/python-to-manage-redundancy-in-text-file-leaving-text-within

Comment: @aseyraamsram, Please give examples that can show what you want clearly in the new question.

Comment: @falsetru consider `he1("yes") , he1("fine")` i need the expected output as `he1("yes") , he2("fine")` ,i mean here he1 is same but it has unmatched text within "" i need to only consider the line not the text within  `""`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

seen = {}
#open file
f = open('1.txt')
#read through file
for line in f:
    #does the line has anything?
    if len(line):
        #regex, for example, matching "(hello [space])(ram or gate)(number)"
        matched = re.match(r'(.*\s)(.*)(\d)',line)
        words = matched.group(1) #matches hello space
        key = matched.group(2) #matches anything before number
        num = int(matched.group(3)) #matches only the number

        if key in seen:
            # see if { ram or gate } exists in seen. add 1
            seen[key] = int(seen[key]) + 1
        else:
            # if { ram or gate } does not exist, create one and assign the initial number
            seen[key] = num
        print('{}{}{}'.format(words,key,seen[key]))
```

Comment: could u explain the code,please?

Comment: @aseyraamsram, comments added